# Pandas groupby agg fills the table up with copies of the column headers

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame containing text which spills over multiple rows, and I want to merge together sets of the rows with the same index.  Most of the time it works.  However in some cases, instead of merging the columns, it simply smears copies of the column headers all across the DataFrame.

I'm using the following code:

```
table = table.groupby(chosen_column).agg(lambda x: ' '.join(
        x.fillna('').drop_duplicates()))
```

Table before (after some processing):

```
   index                     no_header_2  no_header_3 no_header_4  no_header_3 unit_price  no_header_3
0    2.0             Production Supplies  22 MAY 2019           4         text      35.66       142.64
1    2.0             Production Supplies  22 MAY 2019           4         each      35.66       142.64
2    4.0  Supplier Product Number 123456  22 MAY 2019           6         each      13.24        79.44
3    4.0             Production Supplies  22 MAY 2019           6         each      13.24        79.44
4    6.0  Supplier Product Number 234567  22 MAY 2019           3         each      21.35        64.05
5    6.0             Production Supplies  22 MAY 2019           3         each      21.35        64.05
6    8.0  Supplier Product Number 345678  22 MAY 2019          10         each       6.03        60.30
7    8.0             Production Supplies  22 MAY 2019          10         each       6.03        60.30
```

Table after (cut off when printed)
It's also not clear to me why the index is added as a level-2 header and is below printed on it's own line.

```
                                                        index  ...                                        no_header_3
unit_price                                                     ...                                                   
13.24       index no_header_2 no_header_3 no_header_4 no_h...  ...  index no_header_2 no_header_3 no_header_4 no_h...
21.35       index no_header_2 no_header_3 no_header_4 no_h...  ...  index no_header_2 no_header_3 no_header_4 no_h...
35.66       index no_header_2 no_header_3 no_header_4 no_h...  ...  index no_header_2 no_header_3 no_header_4 no_h...
6.03        index no_header_2 no_header_3 no_header_4 no_h...  ...  index no_header_2 no_header_3 no_header_4 no_h...
```

Any advice would be appreciated.  I'm trying to figure out what the headers are being copied into every cell like this, and I'm trying to figure out the right way to do this.  The goal is that all the text sharing the same index will be appended together into a single cell, with duplicates being dropped.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the **dataframe to a python list** with

```
DF.values.tolist()
```

and then you can use the `string.join()` on each list. 
This will always work for you.